# What's the word or phrase for sending an image telepathically?

Tags: word-request, phrase-request

What's the word or phrase for sending an image telepathically?

I was thinking "project an image into someone's mind", but after looking at the definition the best match I could find were:

> 8. (tr) to send forth or transport in the imagination: to project oneself into the future.
> 9. (tr) to cause (an image) to appear on a surface

But none of them really seems to mean what I want, especially the second one. The first one I am not sure, because the example seem to suggest it's one's own imagination.

Comment: "Send" is the word.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SF stories involving some sort of telepathy, either via some machine, or via some innate power of the mind, the verbs "project", "transmit", and "send" are most often used. In each case this would be an extension of the current sense  of those verbs, but if we developed such an ability, I would expect such new senses to be developed, just as the creation of "magic lanterns" and then movies caused "project" to develop a new meaning.

In those stories where the author wanted a specific term, usually a new term was coined that is specific to the story. There has been no widely shared term for this meaning that I know of, and I am moderately widely read in SF.